# node js : save entered line breaks to mysql?

Tags: javascript, node.js

How should I save the user-entered line breaks from a text area to MYSQL database in `nodejs`?

I'm trying to save every word space and line-breaks from textarea. I am trying to save the result from db in the following way

in textarea :

```
First line
second line
```

I am getting the result in this manner

```
first%20linesecond%20line
```

i want the result in db to look like in the following format in the text area...

I know that if it was in php I could have used nl2br() like https://www.php.net/nl2br
But i want to know and use it in `nodejs`.

How should I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never worked in nodejs, but this should work in js environment.

```
function nl2br (str, is_xhtml) {
  var breakTag = (is_xhtml || typeof is_xhtml === 'undefined') ? '<br ' + '/>' : '<br>';     
  return (str + '').replace(/([^>\r\n]?)(\r\n|\n\r|\r|\n)/g, '$1' + breakTag + '$2');
}
```

[Reference](http://phpjs.org/functions/nl2br/)

Answer (score 2):

Simply adding a little css to the element worked like a charm for me:

```
table tbody td {    
white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, basically, you will have to replace all your '\r\n', '\r' and '\n' to `<br />` before inserting the value into the database.

```
temp = "First Line\nSecond Line"
temp.replace('\n','<br />')
```

Comment: yes,like that what i want..but how can i achieve to be like that?can you show me the code or link discuss about that?sorry I'm newbie in nodejs..:D

Comment: Well, even I am not that great with node. But i guess this should help: https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql